# How to block any site?

Tags: 14.04

I have installed a ubuntu 14.04 in my company, and I want to block websites in my browser Firefox/Chorme, but how can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Mozilla Firefox

Using Firefox you can use [Block Site](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/blocksite/) add-on to block any websites (blacklist) or allow only certain websites (whitelist). Here’s a screenshot from its preferences (sorry for my small display):

[image: blocksite preferences]

### Google Chrome

And in Chrome/Chromium it seems there is [an extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-site/eiimnmioipafcokbfikbljfdeojpcgbh) from the same developers.

### Opera

Some time ago I was using Opera for its bits and whistles. There’s a *built-in* functionality to block contents there, under Preferences > Advanced > Content > Blocked Content.

---

I personally prefer the way @sparkmood mentioned here. It’s browser-independent. Brilliant!

Comment: and for Google Chorme??

Answer (score 20):

You can add blocked websites to `/etc/hosts` and point them to localhost.

```
    127.0.0.1 firstblockedwebsite.com

    127.0.0.1 secondblockedwebsite.com
```

by this way ,blocked websites will show localhost, don't forget to check `/etc/hosts` permission.

Comment: I had another problem and this answer helped me big time :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "addblock plus" addon. together with "myscript", you can block selectively whatever you want easily.

Comment: How can I use this from addblock plus?

Comment: if using Firefox, go to https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/ and check the popular addons on the right of the page.

Comment: for Chrome, a google search  for "addon adblock for chrome" will point you to the addon. :)

Comment: This is not a good deal because this block can easily be bypassed by using a different browser. Better block the sites in /etc/hosts

Comment: Whether it is a good deal or not depends on the intended use. I think the question is not very well formed. if he intends to prevent adds (add serving sites) an addblock addon will serve the purpose very well. it will update its list regularly and would also allow for custom blocks with a right click. editing the host file each time would be a hassle.

Comment: however, if he meant that he set up a server for the intention of controlling access to the internet, thus use it as a content filtering system, again using specialized software (router/firewall/proxy) will be better from a management perspective. a host file edit would be practical for a limited set of sites. will he be the sole user? we are overguessing ourselves.

Comment: @annndrey If I use /etc/hosts for block websites, can I use for block a some hours? Or not?

Comment: Sure, just create two files, /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny. The first will be an original hosts file with no blocks and the second should contain blocked sites records. After open your crontab (usually with sudo crontab -e) and paste there two lines: "0 9 * * * ln -f /etc/hosts.deny /etc/hosts" and " 0 22 * * * ln -f /etc/hosts.allow /etc/hosts". It will block any sites listed in hosts.deny from 9AM to 10PM.