# how to block a site

Tags: websites

just saw sparkmoods answer to this question:  [How to block any site?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491393/how-to-block-any-site/491399#491399)  but he didn't provide enough information for me to act on his answer.  I'm not sure where /etc/hosts is.

Comment: "I'm not sure where /etc/hosts is." What's the problem? That is the correct location.

Comment: `/etc/hosts` is a file under the directory named `etc`, under `/` (the root of your filesystem). There is plenty of information. If you don't really understand UNIX paths, you may want to do some research on the filesystem.

Comment: thank's  Zacharee,  my appologies for not trying harder.  I couldn't find it because I didn't realize the terminal didn't open already at the root.  now I just need to change the permissions.  I've tried sudo gedit /etc/hosts in the terminal, as suggested by Gabriel, and it didn't like it:

Comment: mikethe1wheelnut@mikethe1wheelnut-OptiPlex-9010:~$ sudo gedit /etc/hosts
[sudo] password for mikethe1wheelnut: 

(gedit:5719): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

(gedit:5719): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
mikethe1wheelnut@mikethe1wheelnut-OptiPlex-9010:~$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily edit /etc/hosts by typing `sudo gedit /etc/hosts` in the terminal.

What you are doing here is exactly what people commented on your question: there is a etc folder at the root of your filesystem and there is a hosts files inside the etc folder. There is no extension to this file, it is a plain text file called hosts.

You edit it and the system knows where to go when looking for a given nameserver. So if you wanna block google you add

```
127.0.0.1    google.com
```

On your hosts file.

On a sidenote, 127.0.0.1 is an special address every IPv4 computer uses to refer to itself, which explains "localhost". Anything you point to it points to itself, therefore blocking the content.

EDIT: I'll post that to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

`hosts` is a file in the directory `etc`
The full path name would be `/etc/hosts`.